# Displaying full product description on product lightbox

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Is there a WooCommerce add_action to display the full product description, this is the text found in the main text edit window (not the Product short description)

After a quick google search I was only able to find advice on adding the short description. The `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt`.

I'm trying to add it after the `woocommerce_show_product_saleflash`.

The light-box php is shown below.

```php
  <?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_lightbox_summary' );
  ?>
  </div>

  <div class="product-info summary large-6  col entry-summary" style="font-
size:90%;">
    <div class="product-lightbox-inner" style="padding: 30px;">
    <a class="plain" href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
    <div class="is-divider small"></div>
<div><?php the_content(); ?></div> 


    <?php
      do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_lightbox_summary' );
    ?>

    </div>
  </div><!-- .summary -->

</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

</div><!-- product-container -->
</div>

<?php do_action('wc_quick_view_after_single_product'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full product description is set in a tab, so the corresponding template is located in:
 `single-products/tabs/description.php`.

You can unset easily this tab: [Editing product data tabs (Removing tabs)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/#removing-tabs)

Then you can add this code anywhere, using any hook (the code from description.php template):

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

You can also use:

```
global $post;
echo $post->post_content;
```

Or (if the WC_Product object is available):

```
global $product;
echo $product->get_description();
```

Comment: Thanks Loic! Where exactly do I add `global $post;
echo $post->post_content;` In the above php file so it displays along with the rest of the content

Comment: @Joe I think it goes somewhere in `content-single-product-lightbox.php` file no? … This depend on where you want to output it… And I think that you will need to embed it in some `<div>` tags (you will see after, once you get some display) .

Comment: Right am adding it on  `content-single-product-lightbox.php ` page. Can't seem to get it show up. I've removed the tabs. I changed the code above to show where i'm adding it.